# How useful is GraphQLError() provided in Graphene?

Tags: python, exception, graphene-python, flask-graphql

The python graphene documentation does not mention anything about graphQL error. Under what scenarios is it useful, does it have any advantage over a simple `raise Exception('Authenication Failure : User is not registered')` ?

I did my homework and found this in it's constructor,

```
def __init__(
    self,
    message,  # type: str
    nodes=None,  # type: Any
    stack=None,  # type: Optional[TracebackType]
    source=None,  # type: Optional[Any]
    positions=None,  # type: Optional[Any]
    locations=None,  # type: Optional[Any]
    path=None,  # type: Union[List[Union[int, str]], List[str], None]
    extensions=None,  # type: Optional[Dict[str, Any]]
)
```

But apart from message, I don't understand when the other options would be most useful. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The `GraphQLError` class on Graphene comes from [graphql-core](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core) which is the Python implementation of GraphQL-JS, where you can find the same [GraphQLError](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/error/#graphqlerror) class.

This is used to get extra information about the location, the node kind and the stack trace of any validation/parsing error while executing a graphql query.

You can read more at the [official spec doc](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Errors) :)